# Why is java.util.Random slowing later lines of code?

Tags: java, random, time

I am trying to test the runtimes of various disk accessing patterns and have noticed that any time I use a randomly generated data set the execution takes roughly 2.5 times as long as usual, for both a cached and noncached access method. The non-cache, straight to disk, accesses have the same execution times for all of the other access patterns. The random accesses are the only ones that differ by a significant amount.

Is there a reason that the `//testing stuff here` section of my code runs slower when using `accessPattern[i] = rand.nextInt(1000);` rather than `accessPattern[i] = i * 2;`? I pass the elements of accessPattern[] one at a time to another function in the testing section, but I do not see why this would be affected by initializing the array using Random.

```
private void testRandomAccesses( ){
    SysLib.cout( "Random Access Test\n" );
    Random rand = new Random();
    int accessPattern[] = new int[400];
    for ( int i = 0; i < 400; ++i )
        accessPattern[i] = rand.nextInt(1000); //slow execTime
      //accessPattern[i] = i * 2; //fast execTime


    startTime = new Date().getTime();
    //testing stuff here
    for ( int i = 0; i < 400; ++i )
        SysLib.rawwrite( accessPattern[i], testBlock ); 
    endTime = new Date().getTime();
    execTime = endTime - startTime;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking "why does a random disk access pattern take longer than a sequential access pattern?"?

Comment: disc heads don't move unless they have to (for speed reasons). Even if you separate the reads one at a time the head isn't going to go anywhere in between so you still get the benefit of having it close to its destination.

Comment: No. Even if I access a different block every time, I get speeds 2.5 times faster than if I initialize the array using Random. Something about Random seems to percolate into the later lines of code, when I am timing the execution.

Comment: The code you are showing doesn't do any disk access. The comments above the code don't seem to be demonstrated in the code.

Comment: That sounds a lot like comparing a random access pattern to a sequential access pattern, unless you can clarify exactly what you're doing in "testing stuff here"/

Comment: Without expanding `// testing stuff here` Into actual code, answers will be wild guesses at best

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thank you, you've made me realize that I did not take into account the head movement time when creating my worst-case access pattern. The access pattern of (i * 2) would guarantee a cache miss at each access, but the disk head does not have to move a lot. Using Random, the head will move much more, even though the cache may have hits, and is resulting in a longer testing time. I guess I was asking the wrong question because I was ignorant to the real issue. Thanks again, everyone!